# Meaning of 'Pivots' in the below context

Tags: meaning-in-context

1. There are exceptions, of course, but most great companies start with a great idea, not a pivot.

2. If you look at successful pivots, they almost always are a pivot into something the founders themselves wanted, not a random made up idea.

Comment: A "pivot" is a point around which you make a turn.  Eg, the business starts off heading in one direction but pivots and heads off in a different direction.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding; in this context it's a business term used to describe a change in direction of the business (Normally in a start-up).

The [[FT Lexicon]](http://lexicon.ft.com/Term?term=pivot) lists *Pivot* as follows:

Definition of pivot

When used in relation to entrepreneurship, pivot (which generally refers to a shift in strategy) describes the tortured path that most start-ups go through to find the right customer, value proposition, and positioning.